# Borders when row has data but no border if empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that I want to dynamically add borders to filter results.  I have it working where it adds the borders, but when i select another filter it keeps the rows with previous data borders.  So if data set is smaller it has all empty borders under it.  How would I fix this with this script?

```
function onEdit(ss) {
  var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = classeur.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = ss.getRange("A5:a"); // Modified
  range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var offsetRow = range.getRowIndex(); // Added
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0]) { // Modified
      ss.getRange("A" + (i + offsetRow) + ":P" + (i + offsetRow))
      .setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", 
       SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM) // Modified
      .setBackground('#FFFFFF');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getMaxRows(),sh.getMaxColumns()).setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
  var range = sh.getRange(5,1,sh.getLastRow()-4,1); // Modified
  range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    if (values[i][0]) { // Modified
       sh.getRange(i+5,1,1,16).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM).setBackground('#FFFFFF');
    }
  }
}
```

You cannot call this function from the script editor unless you supply the event object.